keep/stretch a frame for more time during a video
How can I do this with QuickTime (sorry I don't know the exact nomenclature):

I have a saved recording of my screen (i.e. the question is about/for mov files)
I want to replace the video (only!!!; keep the audio part intact) from a certain moment to another moment with a static image OR I want to stretch the time an image/frame is displayed in the video for a longer time.

Is this possible with the default apps from MacOS Sonoma 14.5? And if so, how? (I'm new to MacOS ecosystem, so please give me a step-by-step recipe.)

What research have you done so far? This is very much possible, but not with QuickTime. You could use something like iMovie, which is a free Mac App.
